# Is it okay to delete the parent alternate layout in adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, layout

I regret the choice of 8x10 pages in a 250 PG. book, now wish it were 8.5x11 pages. I created an alternate layout for the latter and want only that. Is there a problem with me deleting the parent layout? Windows10, InDesign cc.

Comment: Have your tried just changing the document properties?  You generally don't want to delete the Master Page unless you have a replacement, but it all depends on how your document is set up.